# Views Exposed TID Filter Hidden Behind Body

Tags: theming, views

Hello i have an exposed filter on my view allowing folks to seach by term. When folks start typing though only the first option on the list is shown and he rest is hid behind the body of my website.

You can view it here-
[my exposed filter](http://onlinebanter.com/latest/all)

Its the 2nd from the left in the red bar view up top.

Its driving me mad.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is just a minor problem with the `overflow` property of the parent element. The following CSS rule (specific to your page) should fix it:

```
#preface-top.row,
#block-views--exp-latestnew-page_1.block {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: thanks Amarnath. it sounds like is should work but it hasnt. ive added #block-views--exp-latestnew-page_1 {
  overflow: visible !important;
} and cleared my cache but still the problem continues. very odd.

Comment: Have updated my answer. Can try again?